# record Timestamp cloudpage UpsertDE

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

I'm working on a customer satisfaction system and I would like to record the time when the user has clicked one of the emojis.

Is there a way to do this?

This is what I have so far

Cloud page code

```
%%[

    SET @CustomerID = RequestParameter('CustomerID')
    SET @EmailAddress = RequestParameter('EmailAddress')
    SET @emoji_selected = RequestParameter('emoji_selected')

    UpsertDE('emoji',1,'CustomerID',@CustomerID,'EmailAddress',@EmailAddress,'emoji_selected',@emoji_selected)

    ]%%
```

HTML code

%%[

```
    SET @CustomerID = AttributeValue('CustomerID')
    SET @EmailAddress = AttributeValue('EmailAddress')

    ]%%

    <table align="center" style="text-align: center;font-family:arial;font-size:9px;">
    <tr>

    followed by the html/css...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [now()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Now.htm) function to get the current timestamp, resulting in following code:

```
%%[

SET @CustomerID = RequestParameter('CustomerID')
SET @EmailAddress = RequestParameter('EmailAddress')
SET @emoji_selected = RequestParameter('emoji_selected')
SET @clickTime = Now()   
UpsertDE('emoji',1,'CustomerID',@CustomerID,'EmailAddress',@EmailAddress,'emoji_selected',@emoji_selected,'clickTime',@clickTime)

]%%
```

Please observe, this timestamp will be stored in UTC-6. If needed, you will have to adjust it to the relevant local time zone using [SystemDateToLocalDate()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/SystemDateToLocalDate.htm):

```
set @clickTimeLocal =  SystemDateToLocalDate(@clickTime)
```

Comment: Thanks @Lukas..